# How To Define A Callable Variable in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii2

When I use yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth,

I want to custom `public $auth` which is @var callable, so that I can use it like this:

```
$identity = call_user_func($this->auth, $username, $password);
```

but how to define it with below code?

The following code is a typical implementation of this callable:

```
function ($username, $password) {
    return \app\models\User::findOne([
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
    ]);
}
```

Why can't I define it like this (error report)

```
public $auth=function ($username, $password) {
    return \app\models\User2::findOne([
        'username' => $username,
        'password_hash' => $password,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

remember to name the function appropriately. Rather than call a variable call the function, or if you need added functionality extend the function

```
public functionAuth ($username, $password) {
    return \app\models\User2::findOne([
        'username' => $username,
        'password_hash' => $password,
]);
```

Also I wouldn't recommend editing yii files, I'd always make a new function extending it and then add the customisation you're after

Comment: but I need to use below code to call the `callable variable`:                  //$identity = call_user_func($this->auth, $username, $password);

Comment: If you could explain in more detail what you will be doing with it, I can help further. Is it a login system you're building?